# Using Pipe + Directive to style an element

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 4 and I would like to ask what is the best practice to do the following:

I need to "mark" (style to the color red) a negative number that is inside a **div** or **p** whatever. Sometimes I need to make a calculation (to call a function) and that function will result in a negative or positive number (currency type) or the entire text will come from a database.

What is the best practice to do it? Should I use a Pipe together with Directive?

> Example : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer $-123.45 adipiscing
>   elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget $456.78 dolor.

In the above text I should style it red when it finds a negative value and leave it unchanged when it finds a positive value. With Pipe I can search for a '-' sign but how can I avoid to check twice an element?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to change color of the value inside a string?

Comment: It's not safe to check a string for '-' sign to find a negative number.

Comment: ngClass is the option not pipe or directive

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working answer. It works fine with any element.

Usage: open your app.module.ts and insert:

```
import { chknegDirective } from './chkneg.directive';
```

and in the @ngModule: chknegDirective

then use it in any html tag:

```
<p chkneg>Using P = Lorem ipsum dolor sit -123.45 amet, consectetur -456.76 adipisicing elit. Vel commodi.</p>
```

And here is the file (I called chkneg.directive.ts)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[chkneg]' })
export class chknegDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        let str = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
        this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.chkNegativeNumber(str);
    }

    chkNegativeNumber(str) {
        function addSpan(match, offset, string) {
          return (offset ? '<span style="color: red">'+match+'</span>' : '')
        }
        return str.replace(/[-][0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})/g, addSpan);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ngclass or ngstyle, i.e.

```
<span [ngClass]="{'classRed':money<0}">{{money}}</span>
```

a completed example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample-app',
  template: `
      <p *ngFor="let item of myList; let idx = index">
        {{item.texto}}\t<span [ngClass]="{'classRed':item.money<0}">    {{item.money}}</span>
      </p>
  `,
  styles:[`
           .classRed {
                color: #ff0000;
           }
         `],
})
export class AppComponent {
  myList=[
            {"texto":"texto1","money":3.2},
            {"texto":"texto2","money":-10.2},
            {"texto":"texto3","money":-4.5},
            {"texto":"texto4","money":-9.2}
            ]
}
```

Comment: I'd like to understand your answer better. If I have a text with, say, 10 paragraphs and several negative numbers, will it work for * all * the negative numbers of div / p? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I figure out you have an array of items and you use a ngFor (see edited response)

Comment: Thanks for your partial answer, though, it's not what I'm looking for. As I made clear in my question, I needed a way to check any tags, and when they are numbers (negative) apply a style. Your solution works inside an array and this array probably needs to be populated first. The solution I presented works better, since it works on any tag, just put the selector with the tag. Example: <div chkneg> ... any text size here ... / <div>. Take a look at my answer. Thank you.